# Philadelphia to Cape May - Route 55 or Atlantic City Expressway

Tags: planning, road-trips, new-jersey, philadelphia

I'm going from Philadelphia to Cape May.  It seems like the Atlantic City Expressway, then the Garden State Parkway is the way to go.  I noticed Route 55 to 47/347 also leads to Cape May, with quicker access to the bay side (where I'm staying).  It looks more direct, though may have single lane roads.  So my question is, is this a better route to go?  **By better, I mean faster time wise, with less traffic backup (speaking generally), to quantify, which I will be travelling on the weekend.**

Even though Route 55 is or was labelled the "Cape May Expressway", is the Atlantic City Expressway route the best?

Comment: Depends on time of day, day of the week and other factors and I don't think that we can provide a traffic report.  The average case can be done using mapquest.com or maps.google.com

Comment: Even with edits.  Travelling on Saturday Morning would be less congested then travelling on Friday night.  Going to Cape May on Sunday evening might be a complete breeze since everyone would probably be leaving.  If you will be doing this on a holiday weekend you might as well leave 1 day prior to start of the weekend.

Comment: If you are traveling on summer weekend, the 55/47 route is incredibly congested, take ACE To GSP. Any other time of year, or day of the week, the 55/47 is the most efficient route.